# How would I go about using NODEJS and AWS to create an application that saves uploaded PDF's and allows another user to view them

Tags: node.js

I am currently a Computer Science student working on an independent project. However, I am lost on how to go about using some of the technologies I know to hopefully create an application.

I wanted to use NodeJS to create a website that allowed certain users to use the website to upload PDF's to an admin user. This admin user would be able to see all of the uploads in chronological order and load the PDF of any user. [The example I would give would be to have a teacher collecting HW from his/her students. Each student should only be able to upload his/her homework while the teacher should be able to view all homeworks.

How exactly would I go about storing and working with these PDF uploads? Is it common to just store PDF's in an AWS database? Furthermore, how would I go about allowing the host user to save and access these PDF's?

Sorry for asking such a general question, but I was wondering if anyone had any insight on the technology/frameworks/libraries that would be helpful about going about this. The technology for full-stack that I am most familiar with is using NodeJS and EJS Html Pages to save data.

Answer (score 0):

1. use aws-sdk library to upload the files to s3. You will probably need to use the stream apis
2. for viewing you can either track the metadata of the files in a db, or if its not needed you can list the s3 bucket and show all the files. For each files you can supply a download link

before you deploy you can test it locally. To deploy you can use heroku
Important things to note is the keep the aws credentials secured at all cost!